# join two different files into one file inside a zip (or elsewhere compressed) file

Tags: join, compression, zip, append

I have two files inside a zip file.

Now, imagine these two files are big... REALLY big... so big that I can't uncompress them into my old, poor, tiny hard disk.
However, they are simple txt files, so the zipped version is quite small.

I need to JOIN the two files into ONE single file.
As they're too big to extract, I need to do this INSIDE the zip.
Is there a way to do this?

Example:

"compressed.zip" contains "part_1.txt" and "part_2.txt".
I want "compressed.zip" to contain one file, called "part_1_and_2.txt".

(If it's not possible with zip, I can pick another compressor... but the idea is the same: each uncompressed file is bigger than total capacity of my hard disk)

Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need to ensure that the storage requirements are low; I don't think the operation needs to occur "within the zip file" per se.  You can do this with command-line tools (in Linux or with similar tools via Cygwin) in the following way:

Start with a tarred, gzipped file with your input files in it.  Let that be compressed.tar.gz.  Then you can extract the contents of the gzipped tar archive to standard output and pipe it back to gzip:

```
tar xzf compressed.tar.gz -O | gzip > part_1_and_2.txt.gz
```

The resultant compressed file is the text of part_1.txt and part_2.txt concatenated (though I suppose it is not the same as having a tar archive that contains one file, but perhaps this will be sufficient).

If you need to do this within a program, I would guess that [libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/) and [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) can perform this functionality programmatically, or you can run a script from your program.

Comment: I will try this, but I have one question: when the script extracts the contents of the gzipped tar archive to standard output, in order to pipe them back to gzip, what happens if there's no room for them?
I'm asking this because the uncompressed content of the tar.gz file exceeds the free size of my hard disk. Is the script still supposed to work?
Tnx

Comment: Yes, this should work even if there is no room on disk or in memory for the unzipped archive.  Each step incrementally reads the result of the prior via a pipe and writes to a pipe until the very end.  A tar file can be incrementally processed; it is just a bunch of file records stuck together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`libzip`](http://www.nih.at/libzip/) (which in turn uses [zlib](http://zlib.net/)) to read uncompressed data from the input files in turn and write a new output zip file.  You would not need to store all of an uncompressed file on the mass storage or in memory.  You can read and write a small chunk at a time, as you would without compression.  I presume that you have room on your mass storage for all three of those zip files.